# How To Filter Out Content Grabbed By file_get_contents?

Tags: php, html, file, file-get-contents

I'm getting the source code of a page in a variable $html with this line:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
```

And when I do `<textarea><?php echo htmlentities($html); ?></textarea>`

It works awesome.

Now, suppose, I want to take out every `<h1>` tag in the page with its content in a variable $h1, how do I do this from $html variable?

Comment: You need to use a DOMParser. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php Please come up with some attempts so we can help you out..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Simple Html Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find)

Download the required file and try following code:

```
<?php

require_once ('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
$domHtml = str_get_html($html);
foreach ($domHtml->find('h1') as $element) {
    echo '<h1>' . $element->innertext . '</h1>';
}
```